# Using react query differently in online and offline mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

I'm using react query in my react native app with the following configuration : Stale Time = 3 minutes Cache Time = 5 minutes But the problem is that i need to get data from cache if there is no internet even if 24 hours passed. But with my configuration data is being deleted from cache After 5 minutes. I need to keep this configuration for online mode but if there is no internet i want to to keep data and get it from cache. Please any solution for this Thanks

Comment: The problem you have is that in order to change the cache time, you would have to re-download the content with a new header, but if you've lost internet, you have no way to do so.  Unless you are able to predict when you are going to lose internet in the future, you'll not be able to do what you want.